# VIM use current line number as a command argument

Tags: vim

let's say that I use VIM or (GVIM) to do something like this:

```
:100,100+128s/^1/xx/g
```

So, in other words I am replacing any line starting with "1", and replacing it with "xx". however I am only interested to run this command between line numbers (100) and (128).

However, I would like to be able to do it such that instead of me hardcoding the desired line number (#100 in this case), I want the command takes the line number from the line that my cursor is currently on ! 
How would I do it? 
I know that I echo line(".") will only display it, and not in fact use the line number in the command.

Thanks, 
--Rudy

Comment: Why use `/g` when you know that `^1` will match only once in a line?

Answer (score 5):

From `:help cmdline-ranges`:

> The default line specifier for most commands is the cursor position…

To specify it outright, however, you can use `.` — the special character for the current line. (See `:help range`.)

Comment: oh yea that gave me a hint to actually use the substitute command like this :.,.+128s/^1/xx/g

Comment: Don't forget `.` can be assumed in many places. e.g. `:,+128s/^1/xx/g`